# Facebook JavaScript SDK for FQL with additional parameter

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-javascript-sdk

Facebook deprecated FB.Data.waitOn and FB.Data.query and they recommend we use FB.api instead.

```
More info: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/561/
```

This sounds easy enough, but I can't seem to pass additional parameters with my FQL request without getting an error from Facebook.  For example, I can successfully do this:

```
FB.api({
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'select page_id, name, pic, page_url from page where page_id=' + some_page_id
}, function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

But I'd also like to pass the 'return_ssl_resources=1' additional parameter so that Facebook returns secure resources instead of non-secure ones.  However, if I try the following, Facebook returns a "Parser error: unexpected '&' at position 71" error:

```
FB.api({
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'select page_id, name, pic, page_url from page where page_id=' + some_page_id + '&return_ssl_resources=1'
}, function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

Does anyone know how to pass additional parameters when making FQL requests using the JavaScript SDK?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that we can pass additional parameters as properties in the first argument to FB.api():

```
FB.api({
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'select page_id, name, pic, page_url from page where page_id=' + some_page_id,
    return_ssl_resources: 1
}, function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```