# Facebook still loads http content over https

Tags: facebook, ssl, https

First, I know simular questions get asked all the time. I tried all the solutions on those questions with no results, while my page is very simple. The page allows a user to post a message to his wall, with this html page:

```
<head profile="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

    <title>Bacchi Facebook Campagne</title>

    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <meta content="Media-Enzo.nl / Niels van Renselaar" name="author" />

    <meta content="" name="keywords" />             
    <meta content="" name="description" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/reset.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" media="screen" />


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/default.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));


    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.Canvas.setSize();
        FB.init({
            appId : '252817401440179',
            status : true, // check login status
            cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml : true, // parse XFBML
            oauth : true
        });

    }

    function share_now() {

            FB.ui(
              {
                method: 'feed',
                name: 'Bacchi Like & Win',
                link: 'https://www.facebook.com/pages/Bacchi/312242852138511?sk=app_252817401440179',
                picture: 'https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash2/373503_312242852138511_832874149_n.jpg',
                caption: 'Bacchi',
                message: 'Ik doe mee aan de Bacchi actie!',
                description: 'Bacchi is een merk om mee gezien te worden en om stil van te genieten. Bacchi is voor alle leeftijden, van jong tot oud. Bacchi is dat persoonlijke moment waarin je ontsnapt aan de dagelijkse beslommeringen. Het helpt je bij het besef dat het belangrijk is om van het leven te genieten'
              },
              function(response) {
                if (response && response.post_id) {
                  alert('Bedankt voor het delen!');
                } else {
                  alert('Jammer dat je onze pagina niet hebt gedeeld, maar je maakt nog steeds kans op het gekozen pakket!');
                }
              }
            );

    }
    </script>

    <div id="thanks" onclick="share_now();">

    </div>

</body>
```

Problem; Facebook still loads

`http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/canvas_proxy.php?version=3#behavior=p&method=setSize&params={%22height%22%3A576%2C%22width%22%3A1451%2C%22frame%22%3A%22iframe_canvas%22}`

over HTTP and not HTTPS. Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this question: [Facebook JavaScript SDK for FQL with additional parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599865/facebook-javascript-sdk-for-fql-with-additional-parameter)

For anything to be returned over https you have to use return_secure_resources in each API call

Also take a look here: [Facebook JavaScript SDK over HTTPS loading non-secure items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212016/facebook-javascript-sdk-over-https-loading-non-secure-items)

Comment: Thanks for your response, as you can see on https://bacchi.appsocially.nl/thanks.php that performed changes leave no result, one element is still loading via http.